# Restoring Folder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

By mistake I have deleted one folder from TFS sharepoint portal. How can I restore this folder as the folder is not visible in recycle bin.

Thanks,
Radhika

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio go to "Tools-Options" then Select "Source Control-visual Studio Team Founation Server" and check the "Show deleted items in the Source Control explorer".

You can then right click on a deleted folder and say "Undelete"